# Amazon developer ID

Tags: amazon-mws

I would like to start developing amazon integration for my website
I would like to integrate products, orders etc and I understand I have to use Amazon MWS for API.

To start using MWS I created a developer account
Now the amazon seller has to authorize me by inserting my developer ID.

I can't find IT.

I contact amazon support and they told me to go

Settings -> User Permissions -> Click on visit developer credentials.

But if I go to User Permissions I only see the users list with the possibility to add or edit a user.

[image]
In this image info@e-miko is the owner of the seller account (and I'm logged in as him)
while Martina is me, the developer.
As you see no Developer id is visible.

Any idea?

Comment: When I had this problem it was because I wasn’t the owner of the account. I was an additionally user, given full admin permissions.  But for some reason only the account owner could see the developer section.

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not sure in that case. Sorry!

Comment: @Martina Did you figured it out? Right now I am facing the same problem, any hints?
FYI: I am logged in as Administrator (owner) but also can't see the button.

Comment: @t_io nothing to do, Amazon doesn't answer me! It's from august that I don't receive any feedback!

Comment: same problem for me..

Comment: Did anyone find answer to this ? I have same issue to resolve.